# <mark> text with tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am building my first [Tailwindcss](https://tailwindcss.com) based website. I would like to modify the `<mark>` tag to give marked text a nice look.

This is what I did:

```
mark {
    @apply inline-block pr-1 pl-1 py-0;
    margin-top: 0.15rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.15rem;
}

.mark-rounded {
    @apply rounded-sm shadow-md;
}

.mark-teal {
    @apply bg-teal-500  text-white;
}
```

The problem now is that if a text goes over several lines, the selection becomes a big box.

There is also the problem that the line spacing is increased by the selection. Lines that have a `<mark>`-tag are "pushed apart" and lines without a `<mark>`-tag are closer together.

### full size

[image: full size]

### small size

[image: small size]

### xsmall size

[image: xsmall size]

### My question is

Is there a better (generic) way to style `<mark>`-tags with tailwind?

Comment: You can add tailwind classes to mark tag. `<mark class="">` and customize it for your purpose. `@apply` some tailwind text styling classes and you will be good to go ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake with making your `<mark>` tag a inline block element. Set it to `display: inline` (what it's supposed to be) and you're all good.